# Have google home read a news rss feed outloud

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I am trying to see if there is a way to have google home or assistant read a news rss feed out loud. Similarly to how alexa reads a flash briefing.

I tried submitting my news rss feed to google news briefing feeds and they say you need to have a mp3 file for each feed item.

I want to be able to ask google whats the news in my town and have it read the news rss feed out loud.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've found so far is "Website Reader", which will read the RSS feed from any site you specify.

https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/0000002b54042ee3?hl=en-US&hl=en-GB&jsmode=o&source=web

It's far from perfect though as it only seems to read headlines, not story content.